# Am I able to make non-primative .NET types serializable in WCF?

Tags: wcf, datacontract

When I attempt to  access myWCF service from a web browser on my company intranet by url ~/MyNamespace.MyServiceClass.svc I get the following message:

Type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

MyClass implements each [OperationContract] stubs in my interface, and I added [DataContract()] decorator right above where MyClass : MyInterface, but when I try and decorate the PricipalContext Member in my class with [DataMember], Visual Studio tells me via intellisense that the Attribute 'DataMember' is not valid on this declaration type, it is only valid on property, indexer, and field declarations.

```
    public PrincipalContext GetPrincipalContext()
    {
        PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(
            ContextType.Domain, GetUserDomainName()
        );
        return principalContext;
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2

I am unsure about a few things from the MSDN docs (like above) which say that the point of the DataContract attribute:"Specifies that the type defines or implements a data contract and is serializable by a serializer, such as the DataContractSerializer. To make their type serializable, type authors must define a data contract for their type."

1.) How I am supposed to make serializable a preexisting non-primative class type from .NET framework when I am not the author of said class type (System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext)

2.) All of the examples that I found on MSDN address this issue but only provide examples implementing user-created Custom Class Types such as  Person().

3.) Does System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext have to be serializable for MyWCFService class to contain said type as a member? The primary reason for creating MyWCFService is to expose functionality from the System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement dlls within my organization.

Comment: ~I run into similar serialization issues when implementing in ASMX as well, then it gives me: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Have you tried creating a wrapper class around the object you're trying to serialize?   You could then serialize your wrapper class.  Or create a class that you serialize that acts as an abstraction layer of sorts for the underlying object.

Comment: Does my wrapper need to abstract each non-serializable type from MyClass Member into a primative type eg: String, Bool, List<string>?

Comment: getters and setters feel strange, but the other part of me thinks that perhaps I need to simplify the solution return types. Once I can access my WSDL I will be where I need to be.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. These types are not serializable. You can workaround this issue by creating a wrapper class. You can do something like:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class MyClass
    {
        public PrincipalContext PrincipalContext { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="PrincipalContext")]
        public PrincipalContextSurrogate PrincipalContextWrapper
        {
            get
            {
                return new PrincipalContextSurrogate(PrincipalContext);
            }
            set
            {
                PrincipalContext = value.ToPrincipalContext();
            }
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class PrincipalContextSurrogate
    {
        public PrincipalContextSurrogate() { }

        public PrincipalContextSurrogate(PrincipalContext context)
        {
            ContextType = context.ContextType;
            Name = context.Name;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public ContextType ContextType { set; get; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { set;  get; }

        public PrincipalContext ToPrincipalContext()
        {
            return new PrincipalContext(ContextType, Name);
        }
    }
```